# How to take the standard deviation of an image

Tags: python, image-processing

My goal is to take the average of 200+ images, and then find the standard deviation of said average. Ask the user for a threshold and then compare the threshold to the standard deviation. If the threshold is < the standard deviation for that particular pixel, change it to red [255,0,0]. My issue lies with taking the standard deviation of a pixel. Any help would be appreciated.

```
allimg = []
avg_img=[]
path = glob.glob('podatlamar/*.jpg')

for x in path:
    img = Image.open(x)
    img = np.float32(img)
    allimg.append(img)
avg_img = np.average(allimg, axis=0)

std = [0,0,0]
for img in allimg :
    std += (img-avg_img) ** 2
    std = np.sqrt(std / (len(allimg) - 1))
```

now:

```
 for i in range(0, len(std)): #i is row
   for j in range(0, len(std[i])): #j is column
        if(std[i][j] > float(threshold)).any : 
           avg_img[i][j] = [255.0, 0.0, 0.0]

 avg_img = np.clip(avg_img, 0, 255)
```

etc...

and the result is [all pixels are made red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TktJr.png)

and here is the for loop debugging in action

[The avg_img being changed to [255,0,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwu1l.png)

Snippet of what std looks like

```
[[0.19792126 0.05137325 0.03966657]
  [0.09997863 0.06348856 0.07472634]
  [0.0367469  0.18667144 0.21834356]
  ...
  [0.02421235 0.02454335 0.14083997]
  [0.02319027 0.02351524 0.13969136]
  [0.02285284 0.02317629 0.13930877]]

 [[0.03304812 0.06428259 0.04262938]
  [0.0978733  0.02841616 0.04049174]
  [0.09566899 0.02877731 0.0357872 ]
  ...
  [0.08500231 0.03502595 0.12032651]
  [0.08347222 0.03630779 0.1217759 ]
  [0.08385488 0.03598539 0.12141356]]
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do here. You appear to be taking the mean of the 200 samples at each pixel location, so effectively through the z-axis of 200 images, but you are taking the standard deviation across the x,y dimension of the averaged image. Is that correct? In any case, you really don't want to hold 200 images in memory at once, because images are large. You only need a single float64 or int64 image into which you sum all 200 input images and divide by 200 at the end.

Comment: Your final calculation should be vectorised with Numpy, else you'll be there all day. Try to avoid `for` loops with Python image processing.

Comment: The `.any` is also worrying me as it makes me wonder if you have RGB images rather than greyscale?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The jpg images are RGB and not greyscale.

Comment: At the moment, you have made every image 8x bigger than it needs to be by converting uint8 bytes into float64 and you have stored 200 such images in memory in a list so you are wasting 1,600x the RAM necessary. Can we get that fixed first?

Comment: I converted them to float32. That is the minimum I can do according to teachers instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not provided any input data, I used the individual frames of this animation as my 18 input frames to average across:

[image]

I extracted them using **ImageMagick**:

```
magick animation.gif -coalesce frame-%02d.jpg
```

The code I came up with looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate list of image names
names = glob.glob('frame-*.jpg')

# Load all images into list
images = []
for filename in names:
    im = Image.open(filename)
    images.append(np.array(im))

# Generate average image, where each pixel is the average of that pixel position across all images
average = np.mean(images, axis=0)
Image.fromarray(average.astype(np.uint8)).save('tmp-average.png')    # DEBUG

# Generate stdev image, where each pixel is the stdev of that pixel position across all images
stdev = np.std(images, axis=0)
Image.fromarray(stdev.astype(np.uint8)).save('tmp-stdev.png')        # DEBUG

threshold = 80
average[np.any(stdev>threshold, axis=2)] = [255,0,0]
Image.fromarray(average.astype(np.uint8)).save(f'result.png')
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Just for fun, I made a little animation of the effect of setting the threshold differently:

[image]